# Provide individual access permissions through Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm part of a company where we send sensors to customers and those sensors send data to an Amazon S3 bucket or folder, specific for that customer. I'm trying to create a portal on the web where they can login through Amazon Cognito and see their data. I have followed [User Authentication and Authorization with AWS Cognito](https://1billiontech.com/blog_User_Authentication_and_Authorization_with_AWS_Cognito.php) to create a system that is fairly close to what I want.

It's not quite exactly what I want, though. I want each user to have access to different data, but I don't want to create a new IAM role every time someone new registers an account. I am imagining something like the following flow:

1. The customer receives the sensors (each sensor comes with a sensor ID attached)
2. The customer goes to the online portal, and while creating the account, they input the ID's of the sensors
3. Using the sensor ID's given, a new IAM role is created that gives them access only to the data on S3 that they are allowed to see.
4. Every time the customer logs in, they will assume the IAM role that was created upon registration.
5. If more data is added to the bucket or folder in S3 that they have access to, they will be able to see it.

Not perfectly sure how to make this kind of set up a reality, so any conceptual help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've listed, it sounds like [Amazon S3: Allows Amazon Cognito users to access objects in their bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) might work, given your goal is to secure the data in S3?

Alternatively, you might look in to [Attribute-based access control (ABAC)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_attribute-based-access-control.html), but that would require you to be able to tag the session that you start from Cognito, and I'm not 100% you can do that (like you can with SAML federation).

Comment: @rowanau That's pretty neat! Do you know whether ABAC works with Amazon S3 tags? They are notoriously difficult to access.

Comment: Upon closer inspection none of the useful S3 API calls support the `RequestTag` condition, which would make it a blocker for this particular scenario.

Comment: That first link looks really good! I think that's likely what I'm looking for... One question: It says to put in the "application-name" to the policy (as well as the users files). What is my "application-name"? Is that my App Client name? Thanks so much, again.

Comment: It's just used as an object prefix, so it doesn't matter what you call it as long as it's consistent in both the policy statements. You could probably drop it entirely if you're not mixing in anything else in the bucket.

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting closer... I'm still not able to access it from my little portal page though. To clarify, I have a bucket called "SCB" and inside the bucket are nested folders that go "cognito/applicationname/us-east-2:[the id found in the identity pool]/[files I want access too]". Is that correct? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... Also I'm using the s3.listObjects() function to get the data in javascript. Should I use some other function??

Comment: Do you have an error message you can share? Have you modified the example S3 policies in any way?

Comment: I have not changed the policy as seen in that first link you shared in any way, except for putting in my own information where the red italics are shown. The error message that I'm getting when I call s3.listObjects() is this: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." That function is called within the function getAWSS3BucketObjects(), as seen in the blog post I gave a link to in my original question. Thank you!

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out! I had to add a "Prefix" attribute to the params for the s3.listBucket() function. I just made it equal to the prefix set in the policy, and now I'm pretty sure it's working perfectly! Thank you so so much!